# How to update object values (based on the curr-previous pattern)?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

Assume you have a CSV file with the following simplified structure

```
 LINE1:  ID,Description,Value
 LINE2:  1,Product1,2
 LINE3:  ,,3
 LINE4:  ,,4
 LINE5:  2,Product2,2
 LINE6:  ,,3
 LINE7:  ,,5
```

I am using FileHelpers to read the CSV and have hooked up one the interfaces that allows me me to access the current line, after it has been read. Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3923847/268667) for more background.

The issues is that using that approach I will need to write many more `if` statements to check all the fields that need to be copied. (I have at least, 6 csv files at the moment with the same 'blank' format all having more than 20 fields that need to be copied ~ 120 `if` statements. urggh)

Now this is not a micro optimisation exercise since there will be more files that will have this 'incomplete' format.

How can I update the previous record in an elegant way such that I wont have to write if conditions and declarations for each field?

Comment: Have a list of fields that need to be copied and do what you do for each of the fields in the list.Unless FH provides a way to access the fields in a textual way, you would have to use reflection.

Comment: @jaroslav - see the below...is this along the lines of what you are referring to.

Comment: That's one way of doing it. I would cache the results, though, so you do not have to generate the field list every time you read a record (save the list in an internal collection).

Comment: @jaroslav - good idea, would a static collection work?

Comment: of course, just make sure it's thread-safe as you could be reading multiple CSVs in the same application domain. You can also cache it in the static constructor of the class you are parsing out of CSV and then ask for the field list with `Product.GetCopyFields()` method or however you name it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution is to annotate the required fields using a custom attribute  called `CopyMe` and then use reflection to copy.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",") ]
[IgnoreFirst(1)] 
public class Product
{

    [CopyMe()] public int ID { get; set; }
    [CopyMe()] public string Description { get; set; }

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal)]
    public decimal Val{ get; set; }
}
```

with the AfterRead method looking like so...

```
public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs<RawVolsDataPoints> e)
{
    var record = (Product)e.Record;

    if (PreviousRecord == null)
    {
        PreviousRecord = new Product();
         PreviousRecord = record;
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.ID)) // null value indicates a new row
    {
        var ttype = typeof(Product);
        var fields = ttype.GetFields();

        var fieldsToCopy = fields.Where(field =>
            field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CopyMeAttribute), true).Any());

        foreach (var item in fieldsToCopy)
        {
            var prevvalue = item.GetValue(PreviousRecord);
            item.SetValue(record, prevvalue);
         }
    }
}
```